# Enter UserForm Data into the next empty cell range

Tags: vba, excel

I have a UserForm which takes text entry, and an OptionButton Selection, to enter data onto a Worksheet, with a certain classification.

The entries are placed in a specific cell in the sheet using the value from a counter, i, and can be removed to an "archive" worksheet located on the same workbook, via the use of a button. This pheasibly leaves a free entry in the list. i.e.

```
Job 1 is entered 
Job 2 is entered
Job 3 is entered 
Job 2 is archived

There now exists a space between job 1 and 3.
```

What I am trying to do, is create a loop which will check for an empty Cell range, and place the UserForm data, in the next available empty cell. The data is entered every 5 cells, so A5, A10, A15... etc.

The code I currently have is as follows:

```
If UserForm1.OptionButton1.Value = True Then
  If Range("A" & (5 * i)).Value = "" Then
    ActiveSheet.Range("A" & (5 * i) & ":" & "O" & (3 + (5 * i))).Select
    With Selection.Interior
      .Color = RGB(239, 231, 121)
    End With

    With Worksheets("Active Jobs")
        .Range("A" & (5 * i)) = UserForm1.TextBox1     'Place job 5 cells apart
        .Range("B" & (5 * i) & ":" & "E" & (3 + (5 * i))).Merge
        .Range("B" & (5 * i)) = UserForm1.TextBox2
        .Range("B" & (5 * i) & ":" & "E" & (3 + (5 * i))).VerticalAlignment = xlTop
        .Range("G" & (5 * i) & ":" & "O" & (3 + (5 * i))).Merge

    Set t = .Range("T" & (5 * i))
    Set btn = .Buttons.Add(t.Left, t.Top, t.Width, t.Height)

      With btn
        .Name = "RemovetoArchive" & i1
        .Caption = "Archive"
        .OnAction = "RemovetoArchive"
      End With

    End With

  i = i + 1

  ElseIf Range("A" & (5 * i)).Value <> "" Then
    For i = 1 To 25
    'I can't figure out how to implement the for loop here.
    Next i
  End If
```

Comment: Perhaps taking advantage of `End(xlDown)` will help. Replace the loop with `Range("A" & (5 * i)).End(xlDown).Offset(1)` to get the blank cell to enter data.

Answer (score 0):

So guess I had a brain fart, left this a few days and came back and solved it almost immediately.

Creating a While loop with a new variable C for the range

```
While Range("A" & (5 * c)).Value <> ""
    c = c + 1
Wend
```

This located the nearest empty Cell every 5 cells.